# How to specify flac compression level when converting with avconv?

Tags: avconv, convert, flac, aac

I am trying to convert some aac files to flac files, because aac is not supported by another device I use.
After some multiple attempts to find a solution, searching the Internet, I finally read that ffmpeg was replaced with avconv and that avconv is a fork of ffmpeg. So I searched for how to convert to flac using avconv and found this line:

```
avconv -i (input file) -f flac (output file path)
```

This works well, however, I don't see any flac compression level in that command and I need to have a compression level of 2 or lower, because of cpu resources on the target device. I checked the man-page for avconv, but it doesn't seem to mention flac compression levels at all.

So my question is: How do I specify the flac compression level when converting from any input format to flac using avconv?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `-compression_level` attribute. Man page gives its format as

```
-compression_level[:stream_specifier] integer (output,audio,video)
```

You will likely not need to specify the stream, since you have only a single one in the file, so `-compression_level 2` is your friend.

In the future you may want to check man page for the tools.

1. Open the terminal.
2. Type `man (name of program)`. For example `man avconv`.
3. To search the manual, press '/' and enter the string to search for. In this case i've done '/compression', this was the second thing that was found.

Comment: :D I actually looked at the man page twice, but I didn't see this. Thanks!

Comment: So it would be ? **avconv -i (input file) -f flac -compression_level 2 (output file path)**

Comment: @userDepth Yep.

Answer (score 12):

The option is `-compression_level` and can be set with either `avconv` or `FFmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a flac -compression_level 12 output.flac
```

Interestingly enough the commandline flac encoder offers compression levels of 0-8 but FFmpeg / avconv offers 0-12. The documentation can be seen in 3 places:

**1. Source code:**

The options for flac compression can be seen in `flacenc.c`:

```
/* set compression option defaults based on avctx->compression_level */
if (avctx->compression_level < 0)         <-------------
    s->options.compression_level = 5;     <-------------
else
    s->options.compression_level = avctx->compression_level;

level = s->options.compression_level;
if (level > 12) {                         <-------------
    av_log(avctx, AV_LOG_ERROR, "invalid compression level: %d\n",
           s->options.compression_level);
    return AVERROR(EINVAL);
}
```

I have 'arrowed' in the relevant sections!

**2. Man pages:**

The compression options can also be seen in `man ffmpeg-all` rather than `man ffmpeg` :). This man page shows:

```
compression_level
Sets the compression level, which chooses defaults for many other options
if they are not set explicitly. Valid values are from 0 to 12, 5 is the default.
```

A little confusing with multiple man pages now available for FFmpeg!

**3. Online documentation:**

As 'Miso Soup' pointed out there is also [some documentation available online](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#flac-2) for the deeper options of flac encoding, including the compression options:

```
compression_level
Sets the compression level, which chooses defaults for many
other options if they are not set explicitly. Valid values
are from 0 to 12, 5 is the default.
```

Same as the man pages but perhaps a little easier for some to find and read!

**References:**

- [FFmpeg git: flacenc.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/flacenc.c)
- [FFmpeg codecs documentation: flac](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#flac-2)

Comment: Man, that man page is long! Easier to find the compression_level info here!
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html

Comment: @MisoSoup Good point, I have added these details into the answer as well as reorganised...